# creating dropdown menu using css and jquery

Tags: jquery, css, dropdown

I want to create a multiple `dropdown` menus on a navbar using css and jquery.
but the problem is that when I click on one dropdown other dropdowns show as well.

I gave the `dropdown` ul class `.menu-dropdown` and when I click on one all `.menu-dropdown` classes will be shown.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown-button").on("click", function() {
        $(".dropdown-li").find(".menu-dropdown").css("display", "block");
    });
});
```

This is my jquery code.

Comment: Where is the HTML for the dropdown?

Comment: can you edit your post by adding your HTML code

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".dropdown-button").on("click", function() {
    $(this).find(".menu-dropdown").css("display", "block");
   });
});
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution with click. I guess it's simpler to set the class on the `<ul>`element and not on every single `<li>`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul > li > a").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('ul').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
}

ul.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">News</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If possible we should always do it as simple as possible. So this is with no javascript/jQuery (no click) but with `:hover` so CSS only solution.

```css
ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
}

ul > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">News</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the submenu relative to your menu

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown-button").on("click", function() {
        $(this).find(".menu-dropdown").toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://callmenick.com/post/slide-down-menu-with-jquery-and-css

check out this great code ;P xDD